# Como puedo comparar un String con un Int?

Tags: java

el problema es que estoy haciendo un proyecto donde se hacen solicitudes de cuentas bancarias ya sea personas o empresas, pero necesito ordenar las solicitudes en listas, hice las de Personas ya que me piden ordenarlas por su numero ID, pero las empresas  tengo que ordenarlas por su codigo y organizacion, entonces el codigo es un **int** y la organizacion un **String**, de que forma puedo hacer esa comparacion?

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Debes parsear el int a String o el String a int para compararlos

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor el contexto? Es comparar u ordenar?

Comment: Las empresas deseas ordenarlas  por código y a su vez también organización?

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es comparar el codigo de organizacion (int) con el nombre (String) seria algo tan simple como:

```
int codigo_empresa = 5; 
String nombre_empresa = "5";
int comparacion = codigo_empresa == Integer.parseInt(nombre_empresa)? 0 : codigo_empresa < Integer.parseInt(nombre_empresa)? -1 : 1;
```

Siendo que si el int comparacion resulta 0 son iguales, si resulta -1 el codigo es menor y si es 1 es mayor.

Pero sinceramente dudo que eso sea lo que quieres, si lo que quieres es ordenar por su codigo y luego dentro de eso ordenar por nombre algo asi como

> cod     nomb
>
> 01     a
>
> 01     b
>
> 02     a
>
> 02     c

Pues en ese caso primero ordenlos por codigo y separalos en listas diferentes y luego los ordenas alfabeticamente, para ordenar alfabeticamente usas la funcion.

```
Collections.sort(nombre_array_strings);
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: ya resolví gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir la variable `String` a `int` y eso lo puedes hacer asi:

```
String numero1="2345";
int numero2=4567;
int temp1=Integer.valueOf(numero1); // aqui convertimos el String a int
if(temp1<numero2){
   System.out.println("Entonces el numero 2 es mayor");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Para pasar de String a Integer, hay varias opciones.
>   Yo suelo optar por utilizar el método *Integer.parseInt(String cadena)*

Ejemplo:

```
String numStr = "35";
int numInt = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

> Posibles problemas que nos podemos encontrar:

Que la cadena contenga espacios (tanto en los extremos como entre los caracteres).
Solucionamos esto mediante el método `trim()` para eliminar los espacios de los extremos, y podemos utilizar el método `String.replaceAll()` para los espacios entre caracteres.

*Ejemplo:*

```
String numStr = "   3  5   ";
// Eliminamos los espacios de los extremos:
numStr.trim();
// Eliminamos los espacios del interior de la cadena
numStr.replaceAll(" ", "");
// Aquí ya podríamos parsear a Integer sin problema aparente
```

Espero que te ayude